# Using zenity progress bar with bzcat to dd copy

Tags: dd, zenity

I know there are ways to add a progress bar to `dd`, but I can't seem to get anything to work with my specific situation. Here is what I have so far:

```
bzcat /file/path/goes/here.dd.bz2 | pv -n | dd of=/dev/sdx | zenity --progress --text="Writing" --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

I can't seem to get anything to work. Either the bar sits on 0 until `dd` is done, or it goes up by 2 and finishes way to fast. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I sometimes observe the opposite behavior when copying files in the GUI. The progress bar reaches the end, and then sits there for 15 seconds before the box closes.